# Using ASP .NET 3.5 Themes with Embedded Resources

Tags: .net, dll, embedded-resource, themes

I'm curious if this is possible.  Let me give you an idea of how we're using theming and why we want to use a single resource dll to fetch resources.

We currently have an App_Themes directory with our main (and only at the moment) theme.  Call it MainTheme.  We're using a third party control suite (Telerik) and have several customized CSS files under our MainTheme directory.  We have a skin file (MainTheme.skin) in the directory that has a few customized attributes for some of our controls.

We're trying to optimize our site's performance by reducing the number of page requests (currently around 15 or so).  We do have caching enabled.

We're trying to embed all our theme images, styles and skins into a single Resource.dll thus limiting our page requests.  The problem we're running into is getting ASP .NET to use the Resources.dll as its primary source rather than the root of our MainTheme directory.

We've come up empty on searching for resolutions.  Anyone know if using embedded resources and themes are a mutually exclusive feature or can they be combined?

Also if you have any other suggestions feel free to add.

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know creating a theme dll is not part of ASP.NET it is part of Telerik's suite of controls. I would think their site would show you how to do this and enable it.

I use DevExpress controls and they use a custom http handler added into the web.config to do this.